# Rigify - what are tweak bones,and what do they do?

Tags: armature, bones, rigify

I am quite new in Blender, and try to understand  what are **Tweak** bones which are generated by Rigify.
How is using of them? Unfortunately, I could not find any clear definition of them.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They allow you to deform your character with a lot of freedom.
This can be useful for cartoony animation... although if you don't go too extreme with them, you could possibly use them to create realistic motion.

I have a video where I explain a bit about them:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKgH5zXIYmM&feature=youtu.be&t=1171

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can get rid of them? I tried deleting them from the generated rig and it worked, but how can I set my meta rig to not generate them in the first place?

Comment: No, you can't remove them from your rig. You can hide them tho. Just use the menu in the side panel (Item).